# Run Spring Jobs as jar module packaged in ear and deployed in Jboss

Tags: spring, scheduler

I am trying to run an ear configured with a jar module which has spring bean configuration for scheduled jobs.

Is this possible?

I am trying to eliminate need for a web app to include the scheduler bean context xml.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [CommandLineJobRunner](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html)?  Is this what you want?

You might also have luck with the [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/getting-started.html).